# PIC12F1822 I2C slave mode not working

Tags: pic, i2c, mplabx

I wrote a simple program in MPLabX IDE to test PIC12F1822 I2C slave mode. The program receives data from the master and sends it back in reverse order to the master. But the I2C bus does not work, and I can't find the problem.
Here is my code:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = ON        // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = ON          // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is enabled)
#pragma config CPD = ON         // Data Memory Code Protection (Data memory code protection is enabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset enabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = ON        // Internal/External Switchover (Internal/External Switchover mode is enabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)
// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config PLLEN = OFF      // PLL Enable (4x PLL disabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming disabled)

// general variables
volatile uint8_t Buff[10], BuffPos = 0;

void interrupt isr(void) {
    uint8_t c;
    // I2C
    if (SSP1IF) {
        if (SSP1STATbits.R_nW) {                        // master read (slave transmit)
            if (BuffPos > 0) {                          // if there is new data
                SSP1BUF = Buff[BuffPos - 1];            // load data
                BuffPos--;                              // next byte
            } else 
                SSP1BUF = 0;                            // no more data
            CKP = 0b1;                                  // release clock stretch 
        } else {                                        // master write (slave receive)
            if (SSP1STATbits.D_nA) {                    // last byte was data
              c = SSP1BUF;                              // read received byte
              Buff[BuffPos] = c;                        // store received byte
              BuffPos++;                                // next byte
            }
            else
                c = SSP1BUF;                            // discard address
            CKP = 0b1;                                  // release clock stretch
        }
        SSP1IF = 0b0;                                   // clear SSP1IF
    }
    // bus collision
    if (BCL1IF) {
        c = SSP1BUF;                                    // clear BF
        BCL1IF = 0b0;                                   // clear BCLIF
        CKP = 0b1;                                      // release clock stretch
    }
}    

void main(void) {
    // configurations
    OSCCON = 0b01110000;      // select 8MHz internal oscillator
    OPTION_REG = 0b11011111;  // internal TMR0 clock
    ANSELA = 0;               // all digital
    PORTA = 0;                // all off
    LATA = 0;                 // all off   
    TRISA = 0b101110;         // SCL and SDA input
    SSP1STAT = 0b10000000;    // disable slew rate control
    SSP1CON1 = 0b00000110;    // I2C slave mode
    SSP1CON2 = 0b00000001;    // enable clock stretching
    SSP1CON3 = 0b00001100;    // 300ns SDA hold time, enable bus collision interrupt
    SSP1ADD = 0x31 << 1;      // I2C address
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPEN = 0b1; // enable SSP
    PIR1 = 0;                 // clear interrupt flags
    PIR2 = 0;                 // clear interrupt flags
    PIE1 = 0b00001000;        // enable SSP interrupts
    PIE2 = 0b00001000;        // enable bus collision interrupt
    INTCON = 0b11000000;      // enable peripheral interrupts 
    
    // super loop
    for (;;) {
        CLRWDT(); // clear watchdog timer
    }
    
    return;
}
```

Comment: Be more descriptive than just "does not work".  Does your interrupt handler trigger?  Do you get ACK or NACK back?  What do your signals look like (use a logic analyzer)?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Absolutely nothing. No interrupt handler trigger, No signal change, It is like there is nothing connected to I2C lines.

Comment: Are the I2C lines high or low?  If they aren't changing, either your pullup resistors are wrong or your master is misbehaving.  The slave doesn't get involved until the master transmits the address.

Comment: Also, your pin setup looks wrong.  Both SDA and SCL need to be open-drain (ODCONA) outputs (TRISA) with high level (PORTA).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: There is no ODCONA register on PIC12F1822. I configured A1 and A2 as input and I have external 10K pull-ups. I put another I2C device (DS1307) on the line and the master reads it correctly. I really confused.

Comment: I tested another master device and it worked. There is no problem with the code. Maybe there are some limitations in the master specifications (like speed, etc.).